# Newton Raphson Load Flow of a Power System with Transformers

Tags: power

I have a 13 bus system that I want to apply Newton Raphson to. 3 of the buses have generators. So that makes 1 slack bus and 2 PV buses. 6 of the buses are connected to loads (PQ). 5 buses have transformers. I have no clue how to handle transformers when doing load flow analysis. I converted them to impedances in pu. I'm not sure what the next step is.

The circuit and specs are shown below...
[image: 13 bus system]

[image: 13 bus system specs]

Answer (score 1):

In power flows a transformer can be modelled exactly the same as a line if the per unit system is used. Therefore you can safely model them as impedances.

Check out the page 21 (bracnhes modelling chapter) of the Matpower manual:
http://www.pserc.cornell.edu/matpower/manual.pdf

Comment: the link is unfortunately dead

Comment: Edited the answer with a working link